# How to Install module name pb?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

When I am Running code but it is showing error message because it is showing no module name, how to install pb name module in Collaboratory and anaconda?

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-65b14fed549b> in <module>()
      6 import seaborn as sns
      7 
----> 8 from pb import log_progress

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pb'


%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib import pylab as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (15.0, 8.0)
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

from pb import log_progress
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick google brought me here: https://progressbar-2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#

logically this would be easily fixed by running the commands `pip install progressbar2` or `pip3 install progressbar2`.